Get Bitcoin's wallet change addresses
Is there any way to get the associated change addresses of bitcoin wallet .??
I am using typescript as my backend language.
I have a use case i need to subtract a value going out from user's wallet address.
It is managed if the vin and vout are the same , but if user has a change address then vin ,vout are not same addresse but ultimately then amount goes back to the user..
I need a way to fetch the associated change addresses of a user
